# Excel formula to look up for several specific words and if found save specific text to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

So here is what I'm trying to do:

```
=
IF(RC[-7]="","",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*flower*",A1)),"flowers are beautiful",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*car*",A1)),"car is big",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*tree*",A1)),"tree is green",
"Misc"))))
```

So IF "flower" is found in A1, then in B1 add "flowers are beautiful" AND IF "car" is found in A1 then in B1 ADDITIONALLY add "car is big" etc...

How can I achieve this, I wrote this formula but it works for one find only and it stops... how can I use "AND"..? Thank you

Comment: Do you have Textjoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to get your desired output, instead of nesting each IF statement within each other, you need to write them separately and combine the output.
You can use `TextJoin` to do that. Check the formula below:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, 
IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*car*")>0,"Cars are big",""),
IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*flowers*")>0,"Flowers are beautiful",""),
IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*tree*")>0,"Trees are Green","")
)
```

Here each condition is evaluated separately and all of the results are joined into one text string. The `TRUE` in the formula denotes if you want to ignore empty values.

---

Below is an example of the output:

[image: Example Output of TEXTJOIN]

Comment: Hi. That's exactly how I need it to work, thanks... do you know why I get "#NAME?" as a result?

Comment: Please check the syntax of your formula. The typical reason for this error is that there is a typo in the formula. Check out the following link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want but a much easier method to control the lists and get what you want is vlookup() like so:

[image]

The vlookup() in cell B1 and dragged down is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$4,2,0)
```

Cells E1 to F4 have the lists, change the range in vlookup if you add to them.

And if you want multiple answers in the one cell, then:

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP("flower",$E$1:$F$4,2,0),"")&", "&iferror(VLOOKUP("car",$E$1:$F$4,2,0),"")&", "&iferror(VLOOKUP("tree",$E$1:$F$4,2,0),"")
```

As it appears I did not get part of your question originally.